# Capybara tests - No port in JS assets

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, asset-pipeline, capybara-webkit

Writing some capybara integration/feature tests for my Rails 5 app & they keep failing b/c none of the JS loads. When I looked into it, I saw that in my test env, the script looks like this:

```
<script src="/assets/application.debug-c0cceddfe5721264a37a27717e21b167d46fd27617e66e210764c0dfd36b5992.js"></script>
```

But when it's loaded with selenium, the script looks like this:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/assets_test/application-5c233b506cd224705939cbe7104615eba3c0f51d572dba60e074395a6346472a.js"></script>
```

Notice how it now has the host explicit. However, the test runs on a separate port, for example `:56789`, so the test JS doesn't load since the port isn't specified.

When I go to the link in the above src in the test environment, I get nothing. However, when I add the port number being used for this test, I see the JS file just fine.

What gives? To properly run my integration test, I need to be able to load this JS, and I'm at a complete loss on how to do that.

---

### Here is my configuration:

**test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
  config.assets.prefix = 'assets_test'
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "127.0.0.1"
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.action_view.cache_template_loading = true
  config.eager_load = false
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{1.hour.to_i}"
  }
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.active_storage.service = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
end
```

Figured it out. Commented these lines out and it works:

```
#config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
  #config.assets.prefix = 'assets_test'
  #config.action_controller.asset_host = "127.0.0.1"
  #config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Not sure how they ended up in my code in the first place.

Comment: What configuration are you specifying for Capybara?

Comment: I've tried adding these to no effect:
`Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
  Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"`

Comment: None of those will affect what you're seeing -- could you please add your current config to your question

Comment: Yeah, what are you looking for exactly -- test_helper, rails_helper, test.rb? All of it? Anything else?

Comment: Anything Capybara/test related

Comment: Taking a closer look at my test.rb -- the answer was obvious, after I deleted all the comments that file comes with on default. See above. Not sure how or why those lines ended up there in the first place. Thanks for helping me, Thomas!